# Python: Trouble with cross platform running of subprocesses

Tags: python, windows, macos, python-2.7

I have the following helper method which executes commands perfectly on OSX and only with some commands on Windows:

```
def exec_cmd(cmd):
    """Run a command and return the status, standard output and error."""
    proc = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
    # I like to get True or False rather than 0 (True) or 1 (False)
    # which is just backwards as usually 0 is False and 1 is True
    status = not bool(proc.returncode)
    return (status, stdout, stderr)
```

For example, the following sample commands all work perfectly on Mac using my `exec_cmd` helper:

- `osascript -e 'tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint" to activate`
- `osascript -e 'tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint" to quit`

For example, the following sample commands all work perfectly on Windows using my `exec_cmd` helper:

- `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Powerpnt.exe" /S "C:\Users\MyUser\example.pptx"`
- `Taskkill /IM POWERPNT.EXE /F`

However, the following does not work on Windows:

- `START "" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Powerpnt.exe"`

It errors out with:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Even this doesn't work:

```
p = Popen(["START", "", "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Powerpnt.exe"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

However running that same command on the command line works fine, or even stranger just doing this works:

```
os.system('START "" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Powerpnt.exe"')
```

Why does os.system work, but not the Popen version?  These are just simple open and close app examples, but I'd like to do more as I need to get the stdout output for some commands I plan on running.

Any help on sorting this out is appreciated.  I can't seem  to understand the underlying mechanic of `os.system` vs. `subprocess.Popen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this issue because `START` isn't a program, its a shell command. According to the documentation, `os.system()` "Executes the command (a string) in a subshell", where as `popen` doesn't. `os.system()` effectively spawns a new `cmd.exe` instance, and passes the command to that, where as `popen` just spawns a new process.

You are getting the `The system cannot find the file specified` error because there isn't a program called `START`

Comment: Geez.  You're right.  I'm an idiot.  I guess that's why passing the dreaded `shell=True` for this Popen command it works on Windows.